# INT format to show commas in GridView not working for ZERO values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm using below code to show comma separated values in `GridView` when it is int. But when the Column1 data is 0, `Gridview` doesn't show anything. I need to show value when it is 0.

For e.g. if data is **1111**, it will show **1,111**
but if data is **0**, `Gridview` column will have **empty**.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <%# Eval("Column1", "{0:#,###}")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Could you please help how I can show 0 values as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Column1", "{0:#,###}").ToString()) ? "0" : Eval("Column1", "{0:#,###}"))%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
  <%# Eval("column1","{0:0,000}")%>
```

Comment: Or if it is directly on the column: `DataFormatString="{0:0,00}"`